# python's __getitem__ in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Python's **getitem** makes the class work as a dictionary.

But is there a function in node.js's class that does a similar thing?

My file's content is like below

```js
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs')

class JSONManager {
    constructor (filename, encoding = 'utf8') {
        this.filename = filename
        this.content = JSON.parse(
            readFileSync(filename, encoding)
        )
    }

    commit() {
        writeFileSync(
            this.filename,
            JSON.stringify(this.content)
        )
    }
}
```

But I Don't want to use like `classname.content[value]`. I want to use like `classname[value]`

(Sorry for not telling the exact purpose)

Comment: The above code is valid javascript.

Comment: My mistake. Edited

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve here? All javascript objects can work as a dictionary with using breace or dot syntax..

Comment: Edited(Sorry for multiple edits)

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4z0Ltqpm/)

Comment: I think that @Eldar has provided a solution which is the same as Python's `__getitem__`. However, I would discourage the use of that approach because of the way that classes in JS use `myClass['...']` syntax to access methods. If you use `Object.assign(this,obj);` to assign as suggested, and `obj` has "commit" as a key, it will clash with `JSONManager.commit`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to avoid that dynamic properties are loaded into the `content` property, and want to have them directly on the `this` object.

So use `Object.assign`:

```
    Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(
        readFileSync(filename, encoding)
    ));
```